# Can a single-phase solid solution have a martensitic transformation?

Tags: alloys, phase-transitions

I'm trying to investigate the possibility of martensitic transformation in a non-iron alloy, described as a single-phase alpha-solid-solution (Nickel-Silver $\ce{CuNi12Zn25Pb1}$, CW404J).

I know that Cu-Ni-Zn alloys with higher zinc amounts show even shape memory effects and that $\ce{CuNi12Zn25Pb1}$ is no Shape Memory Alloy.
I also know that Nickel-Silver alloys with Zn>32% are two-phase (alpha-Beta) solid solutions.

So I wonder (and searched) whether there is causality or correlation between being a two-phase (and not single-phase) solid solution and having the ability of martensitic transformation (and Shape Memory Effect)?

Comment: I gave my +1 long ago, but have you found an answer over the last 8 months? Please update us!

Comment: Hi, I asked it also in reddit, you can read the answers there
https://www.reddit.com/r/materials/comments/yme766/question_can_a_singlephase_solid_solution_have_a/